# Математическая задача

Tags: java, математика

Есть задача, она выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я составил программу с помощью `Math.pow`, прошу помощи или совета от спецов.

Cам код выглядит так:

```
package zadaniyeb.java;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        double t1 = (7 * Math.pow(Math.cos(a)))/(Math.sqrt(Math.abs(Math.pow(5 * a + (Math.pow(2 * b))))));
        double t2 = (Math.pow(Math.sin(5 * a + 2 * b )))/(Math.pow(Math.E, cos(a)));
    
        System.out.println(t1 - t2);
    }
}
```

Comment: `7 * Math.pow(Math.cos(a))` вроде в степень не надо возводить в примере. тем более сам метод принимает два параметра, а вы передаете только один

Comment: Math.pow это функция возведения в степень, для вычисления t1 она вообще не нужна. Для расчета t2 она корректно использована только для вычисления значения знаменателя (хотя и там Math потеряли). Значения a и b никак не проинициализированы. Смотрите на ошибки которые выдает IDE при сборке приложения.

Comment: @yolosora тогда что нужно использовать для t1 так же как можно проинициализировать а и б?, я новичок в java мы проходим его только 3 дня поэтому прошу простить мои глупые вопросы))

Comment: `double a = 0.5;` например. Если все `Math.pow` из вычисления t1 поудалять то на глаз будем норм

Comment: @yolosora как думаешь можно написать √|5a+2b| как (Math.sqrt(Math.abs(5*a + 2*b) или надо 5а и 2б писать отдельно и сложить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно разделить чуть мельче, чтобы было нагляднее.

```
double a = 1.4;
double b = 6.9;
        
double numer1 = 7 * Math.cos(a);
double denom1 = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(5 * a + 2 * b));
double numer2 = Math.pow(Math.sin(5 * a + 2 * b), 2);
double denom2 = Math.pow(Math.E, Math.cos(a));
double result =  numer1 / denom1 - numer2 / denom2;

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: спасибо большое, и понятнее и самое главное работает)))